# TwinCat3 - TF6310 TCP/IP - How to Use multiple network cards Send Data

Tags: twincat

I'm sorry, my English is not very good. Please forgive me.

I use Twincat3 TCP/IP Socket to connect with the field device
But there are several IP duplicates and not allowed to modify Deviec Configure

Thanks so much

I want to use the remaining different network cards for communication, but I'm not sure if it's feasible
If possible how to Set that?

Answer (score 0):

For the TCP communication you need IP address and port number. Probably you can change port number of your field device.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).